# Why isn't my method getting called? Expected spy show to have been called

Tags: angular

I have a method:

```
public openTermsAndConditions():void {
    console.log('openTermsAndConditions')
    this.modalService.show(TermsAndConditionsComponent, { class: 'modal-lg' });
    console.log("done call openTermsAndConditions")
}
```

My html:

```
<div class="terms-and-conditions-section">
      <div class="terms-and-conditions-text">
        By clicking on Signup, you agree to the
        <span data-testid="terms-and-conditions-link" class="link" (click)="openTermsAndConditions()">Terms and Conditions</span> and <span class="link" (click)="openPrivacyPolicy()">Privacy Policy</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Here's my test:

```
let spectator: Spectator<SignupComponent>;

  const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
    component: SignupComponent,
    providers: [
      mockProvider(SignupService)
    ],
    mocks: [
      BsModalService
    ],
    imports: [
      ModalModule
    ]
  });

  const createProvider = (signupService: object) => {
    const providers = {
      providers: [
        mockProvider(SignupService, signupService),
      ],
      mocks: [
        BsModalService
      ],
      imports: [
        ModalModule
      ]
    };

    return providers;
  };

 // Other code here

  describe('openTermsAndConditions', () => {
    it('should open the terms and conditions modal when clicked.', () => {
      spectator = createComponent(createProvider({}));
      const modalService = spectator.inject(BsModalService);

      spectator.click(byTestId('terms-and-conditions-link'));

      expect(modalService.show).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Expected spy show to have been called.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/public/pages/signup/signup.component.spec.ts:241:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:368:26)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:273:39)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:367:52)
```

I don't understand, I did the some console.log to verify if the method has been called, and indeed it has been called, but the test tells me that it was not able to call the method `modalService.show`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to setup a spy before your test code can check to see if it's been called.

```
spyOn(modalService,'show');
```

Comment: `const modalService = spectator.inject(BsModalService);` already returns a spy. If I did that, console will just throw an error saying that the method/service has already been spied on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
it('should open the terms and conditions modal when clicked', () => {
    const modalService = spectator.inject(BsModalService);
    const modalSpy = spyOn(modalService, "show").and.callThrough();

    spectator.click('[data-testid="terms-and-conditions-link"]');

    expect(modalSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

This should properly spy on the show method of BsModalService and allow you to test whether it's being called when the terms and conditions link is clicked.

Comment: const modalService = spectator.inject(BsModalService); already returns a spy. If I did that, console will just throw an error saying that the method/service has already been spied on.

Comment: You need to spy on the show method precisely, try it out once, if it throws error let me know